# System of ODEs with different starting points

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to transform a system of ODEs with different starting points into a common starting point(the reason is that Matlab only allows for a common starting point).

The system of ODEs is defined as follows:

$Y'_0(t)=F(Y_0(t),Y_1(t),t)$ and $Y'_1(t)=G(Y_0(t),Y_1(t),t)$

with $Y_0(t_0)=y_0$, $Y_1(t_1)=y_1$.

I also have $t_0 \ge t_1$.

How can I transform this system so that $Y_0$ and $Y_1$ will start at $t_1$?

I know if this is only 1 equation, then I can transform $t$ by applying a transformation to shift it. But transforming $t$ in this case will shift both $Y_0$ and $Y_1$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't know enough about this, but is it possible you could define $Y_0$ in a piece-wise manner?

Comment: Not sure if i understand this correctly, but i don't think i can define $Y_0$ at all. I will be solving this system using Matlab

Comment: I can't speak to the problem of solving this in Matlab, but perhaps you can try some sort of modified [shooting method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shooting_method) wherein you choose different values for $Y_0(t_1)$ and solve the system of equations forward in time until you can zero in on a value of $Y_0(t_1)$ that results in the desired value of $Y_0$ at $t = t_0$.

Comment: Matlab has a dedicated boundary value solver called `bvp4c`. As this solves an implicitly defined problem, there is a strong dependence on a good initial guess.

Answer (score 3):

Such a transformation is not possible, in general. Your problem is a Nicoletti boundary value problem. Consider for example (I write $u,v$ for $Y_0,Y_1$, and $t_0\ge t_1$ doesn't matter; just interchange $u$ and $v$)
$$
u'(t)= -v(t),~ v'(t)=u(t), ~ u(0)=0, ~v(\pi/2)=1.
$$
The general solution of the ODE is
$$
(u(t),v(t))= c_1(\cos(t), \sin(t))+ c_2(-\sin(t),\cos(t)).
$$
Then $u(0)=0$ forces $c_1=0$, and $v(\pi/2)=1$ fails for each $c_2 \in \mathbb{R}$. Thus the problem above is unsolvable and you cannot transform into an equivalent initial value problem. Nicoletti problems behave much more like BVPs than like IVPs (for example the size of Lipschitz constants matter).
A reference is: Lasota, Olech: An optimal solution of Nicoletti's boundary value problem, Annales Polon. Math. Volume: 18 (1966), page 131-139 .